# Why I can only close socket's outputStream first and then close inputstream?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I wrap a socket.getInputStream() by an InputStreamReader, and wrap a socket.getOutputStream() by an OutputStreamWriter. I find that the closing order of these streams really matters but I didn't figure out why.

If I close the outputStream first and then close the inputStream, it works fine:

```
outputStreamWriter.close();
inputStreamReader.close();
```

However, if I close the inputStream first and then close the outputStream, it throws an error:

```
inputStreamReader.close();
outputStreamWriter.close();
```

The error is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:316)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at http.HTTPServer.start(HTTPServer.java:69)
    at http.HTTPTest.main(HTTPTest.java:10)
```

Also, I want to ask do I still need to call `socket.close()` after closing the socket's inputstream and output stream? And if I close the socket first, do I still need to close these two streams?

Comment: The document says `Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.`.

Comment: Closing any `FilteredOutputStream` flushes it and closes the underlying stream. Closing a socket input stream closes it and the underlying socket but doesn't flush whatever output stream or writer you wrapped around the socket output stream.

Answer (score 1):

From [Socket.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close--)

> Closing this socket will also close the socket's `InputStream` and
> `OutputStream`.

From [Socket.getInputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream--)

> Closing the returned `InputStream` will close the associated socket.

From [Socket.getOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream--)

> Closing the returned `OutputStream` will close the associated socket.

So you can't close just one stream intentionally or accidentally. If you're done with the socket, then `Socket.close()` is fine. Although if you're using try-with-resources then the streams may get closed automatically anyway. Depends on your design how to write the logic.

The reason for the exception here is `OutputStreamWriter` buffering bytes, so when you `close()` it writes out its buffer first (if buffer is not empty). If you close the writer first, the socket is still open and the bytes will be written, if you close the reader first the socket is closed and you get an exception.

Comment: Thanks, but if so, why am I able to close outputstream first and then close the inputstream without seeing an error?